# Safe to ground feedback loop of voltage follower

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a simple voltage follower with an [AD822](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD822.pdf) Op amp feeding its output to VIN of an [AD637](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD637.pdf)

The AD822 is setup standard like so:

[image: AD822 Voltage follower]

I want to temporarily ground the feedback loop of the AD822 to inject a failure to keep the incoming signal low. Is this safe? I assume the high impedance of the Op amp will protect it, but would I need a current limiting resistor?

Comment: If you're AC coupled like that, the mean signal at the 637 is already zero volts.  Note also that the 1K resistor you added to the drawing doesn't do anything to the voltage at Vout.

Comment: @ScottSeidman care to explain about the 1k resistor (I'm curious and learning)

Comment: Vout will be equal to Vin regardless of whether the 1K resistor is there or not.

Comment: Why doesn't the 1K resistor have any effect? Wouldn't it be a pulldown resistor?

Comment: It certainly has a current through it, but no, its doesn't function like a pulldown resistor.  Picture what happens when Vin=2v.  If the resistor isn't there, Vout=2 volts, and there is zero current in the feedback loop.  If the resistor is then put in place, Vout is STILL equal to 2V, and now the current through the resistor is 2V/1Kohm= 2ma,, and the op amp pushes out an extra 2ma to supply the current.

Comment: Oh I get it now, what if instead of the 1K resistor I used a 10uF capacitor to ground. Would it effectively create an integrator feedback loop for the opamp?

Comment: Closer.  Think of that feedback loop as being a real solid clamp for Vout=Vin.  Nothing in parallel to that feedback loop will interrupt that, as the op amp will do what it needs to fix it.  What the cap you describe will do is create something approaching a short circuit at infinite frequency.  My recommendation would be to simulate it and see what happens.  You'll see glitches at sharp transitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output impedance of an op-amp is low. Hence, the op-amp would strive to feed all its output straight to ground. This will cause overheating, and if there is no thermal protection in the part, it will be damaged.

Comment: The output of the opamp is capacitively coupled to VIN of AD637 so would I need a smaller cap to ground since I'm dealing with a varying signal to "ground" out the signal low

Comment: Not clear what you mean, please explain?

Comment: There is a 1uF capacitor in series from the output of the op amp to the VIN of AD637. Wouldn't the capacitor offer a lower resistance path for a varying signal than a resistor would to ground? So a pull down resistor to ground wouldn't affect the signal at all?

Comment: @zacharoni16 Please update the schematic in the question with the resistor and capacitor you mention - as I see it now, there's a straight short circuit wire from Vout to ground. A capacitor wouldn't be a lower resistance path than a wire, unless it's a really really long wire or something.

Comment: Updated I assumed a 1k resistor to protect the opamp from over-current.

Comment: @zacharoni16 Then you're good. Not sure you will get the result you're hoping for, but I don't see a risk factor now.

Answer (score 2):

The AD822 is rated for indefinite output short circuits on its Absolute Maximum table. The data sheet states

> While the AD822 is internally short-circuit protected, this may 
>   not be sufficient to guarantee that the maximum junction 
>   temperature is not exceeded under all conditions. With power 
>   supplies ±12 V (or less) at an ambient temperature of 25°C or 
>   less, if the output node is shorted to a supply rail, then the 
>   amplifier is not destroyed, even if this condition persists for an 
>   extended period.

You should be safe for limited durations.  That said, the internal short circuit protection might mean you'd have to put some thought into exactly what you were accomplishing